# check to email is exists or no

Tags: php, email, ping

I want to check entered email address before registering, I found some solutions in SF but these solutions says we should check `MX` or `SMTP` port, but we have some fake emails like :

```
111111@gmail.com
some.email.address@gmail.com
and ...
```

when I check the `gmail.com` domain this domain have `MX` record and there is no problem but this emails are fake !

Is there any way to ping email address with php?

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you can do is send a confirmation email, and ask user to click a link or provide a code you have sent in this email.

Comment: Yes you right, but because we have many registration in day and we send many emails to fake emails in yahoo and gmail, we have a high bounce rate so our IP will lose reputation :-(

Comment: @MajAfy Then introduce [**Captchas**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Capthcas&oq=Capthcas&aqs=chrome..69i57.191j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=Captchas) etc! Prevent the bots! :)

Answer (score 3):

You CAN check for the existence without sending a mail.

After you get the `MX` record, you can use SMTP protocol to communicate with the server directly.

For example: (the lines starting with `>` means input. )

```
> telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
Trying 74.125.129.26...
Connected to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP pa10si7038694pbc.108 - gsmtp

> HELO
250 mx.google.com at your service

> MAIL FROM: <test@test.com>
250 2.1.0 OK rw3si4189390pab.9 - gsmtp

> RCPT TO: <notexists___@gmail.com>
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 rw3si4189390pab.9 - gsmtp
```

If you replace `notexists___@gmail.com` with `111111@gmail.com`:

```
> RCPT TO: <111111@gmail.com>
250 2.1.5 OK il2si7046221pbc.91 - gsmtp
```

In PHP, you can use socket functions to do things above.

**NOTICE:** This approach may not work on some SMTP servers.

Answer (score 2):

The only way i know to check email-addresses is through sending an email to them.

Why do you need to check the e-mail address beforehands? You could just send them an "activation link" what also prooves not only the existance but the person behind the address.

Comment: Yes you right, but because we have many registration in day and we send many emails to fake emails in yahoo and gmail, we have a high bounce rate so our IP will lose reputation :-(

Comment: I don't think that there is any way of checking mail-addresses without the server punishing you for spamming or whatever. But try lujjjh's approach, but I'm not sure how the mailservers will react.

Answer (score 2):

You can send a confirmation mail, so that you know that address works. If that is not an option, you can check of the domain actually exists. That way you disregard `something@non_existing_domain.com`

```
// or use ANY or for other see above link
if (checkdnsrr('non_existing_domain.com', 'A')){ echo 'Domain exists'; }
else { echo 'Domain does not exist'; }
```

Comment: Yes you right, but because we have many registration in day and we send many emails to fake emails in yahoo and gmail, we have a high bounce rate so our IP will lose reputation :-(

Comment: Bouncerate has nothing to do with an email bouncing. Bouncerate is when a user enters your page, and returns to the searchengine without clicking anything